# rails app - jquery document.ready not called when link click, but working when opened in new tab or refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some links in the homepage.

When any of the links are clicked, the new page is being shown. But, when we click the link, document.ready is not being called, so I have to either refresh or press enter on the address bar or copy address bar url and open in new window.

What to do so that when links clicked, document.ready will be called ?

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Some guys want me to put code here, so look at the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("doc ready");
});
```

This console is not being called.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Check in console for the problem,if not then paste code here..

Comment: Are you using some kind of _client side caching_ functionality like the one is provided by jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @fguillen, I donno that, but mine is a rails app, so may be its doing something.

Comment: document.ready has to be called on the current window where the link resides or on the page of the link ?

Answer (score 1):

Ready handlers are unbound once called. You have to use this kind of snippet:

```
$(readyHandler);

function readyHandler(){
    //call on ready or trigger it manually!
}

$('#myLink').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //depending your logic, if calling some ajax method as .load() method, use complete callback/success and recalled method:
    $('#dynamicContentElement').load('myUrl',readyHandler);
});
```

Comment: Even this is functioning exactly the same, mine is a rails app, may be somethng related to that. I have have to ask some rails guys. but thanks fr answer, +1

Comment: @user2139745 rail is a server side language, it will not affect client side language behaviour, here javascript/jquery. You should provide the code you use to load dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You simply assign it to the hyperlink click

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(document).trigger("ready");
});
```

Comment: ha ha, I dont want 'ready' to be triggered before going to a new page(link page).

Comment: BTW, you cannot trigger document ready event as it is a pseudo event, unbound once called and using promise internally

Comment: Do you think $(document).trigger("ready").unbind("ready"); would make it bind again ?